# Delphi XE2 and TurboPower Orpheus

Tags: delphi, turbopower

I am installing TurboPower Orpheus on Delphi XE2. I got Orpheus from sourceforge.net.  The version of Orpheus for Delphi XE2 has four Borland Package Libaries (BPLs):  O408_r160.bpl, O408_d160.bpl, O408br160.bpl, and O408bd160.bpl.

No documentation from SourceForge explains the differences between these libraries.

Can someone decode the filenames for me so I can determine which one of these four libraries to install into Delphi XE2.

Thanks!

Comment: XXXd160.bpl is design time, XXXr160.bpl is runtime

Comment: You would install the O408_d160, which will require that the O408_r160.bpl be in the same folder, and that whatever folder that is, is in your system's `PATH`. The designtime one in turn will load the runtime package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Readme.txt that came with the TP Orpheus initial open source release:

```
2. Package names


TurboPower Orpheus package names have the following form:

  ONNN_KVV.*
   |   ||
   |   |+------ VV  VCL version (30=Delphi 3, 35=C++Builder 3, 70=Delphi 7)
   |   +------- K   Kind of package (R=runtime, D=designtime)
   |
   +----------- NNN Product version number (e.g., 406=version 4.06)

For example, the Orpheus runtime package files for Delphi 7 have
the filename O406_D70.*.

The runtime package contains the core functionality of the product and
is not installed into the IDE. The designtime package references the
runtime package, registers the components, and contains property
editors used in the IDE.
```

**Note**: @WarrenP points out that the text above contains an error (probably just a typo by the author at TurboPower); the "For example" has things reversed - it should say "The Orpheus **designtime** package files for Delphi 7".

XE2 is Delphi version 16, so it would be the pair ending with `r160` and `d160`, with `d160` being the designtime package. I think (but haven't had a chance to confirm yet) that XE2 requires slightly different packages for Delphi and C++ Builder, and that the `br160` and `bd160` refers to `"B"uilder`. I'll try and verify that; I don't have Orpheus on this machine, but I have it on my office machine (legacy stuff), so I'll update when I can. In the meantime, I'd start by compiling the `O408_r160.dproj` and then compile and install the `O408_d160.dproj`; I'm pretty sure those are the ones you need.

Comment: So therefore, just ignore the `br` ones

Comment: @WarrenP, I said the *pair* ending with either `d160` or `r160`. IIRC, the XE2 versions have different packages for Builder and Delphi, but I haven't had a chance to check that yet. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Oddly your snippet of documentation says that the "Runtime" one uses the D suffix instead of the R one, which is most likely a simple typo.

Comment: Not sure; I copied and pasted it directly from the `readme.txt`, as I said. ?? Must be, though. I'll correct that with a quick note as well.